# How to remove header of the table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

[image]

I created this table in rails and when I press the **Delete All**
button it deletes all of the items in the table. But it leaves the header of the table. How can I delete the table header together with other items when pressing the delete all button?

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def delete_marked
        @delete_marked = List.where(:completed => true).destroy_all
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'All marked items were successfully deleted.'
    end

    def delete_all
        @delete_all = List.destroy_all
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'All items were successfully deleted.'
    end
end
```

Comment: at the ' delete all' event, Can you change the style of the table header to {display: none }

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you need to check if there are any `List` items. If there are, you render the headers, otherwise you don't. It's difficult to help you more without the actual view and controller code for the view, but:

```
<% if @items.any? %>
  <h1>header stuff herer</h1>
<% end %>
```

Works as a proof of concept. There are other ways to do it, too; you can use partials: `<%= render "list_table", items: @items if @items.any? %>` is an option too.